# Should session always expire when browser is closed?

Tags: session, usability

This is probably more of a usability question but this seems like a good audience to poll.

**Q:  Should a users session always expire when browser is closed? why or why not?**

If "it depends" please state some examples of when it should, and when it shouldn't expire on browser close.

Comment: is this a general question or about this site or some other site in particular?

Comment: this is more of a general question.  I'm developing an online webstore and the question came up in my head as I was coding part of the user authentication system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should, as an open session enables others to intrude in your system. However, how do you want to detect if the browser is closed? Even with ajax, this is really unreliable.

So define proper timeouts depending on the type of application (ie. bank software 10 minutes, browser game 20 min etc).

Comment: In my particular case, I'm using Codeigniter and they have a config setting that allows me to expire a session on browser close.  I'm not really sure how it works tbh.  There is a setting to "refresh" the session every X seconds.  I'm sure if I turned the number of seconds down, then it would notice that the browser is closed and expire the session after X seconds

Answer (score 2):

Session should always expire with browser close. That way if the user failed to logout before closing the browser their session will not still be open and hackable.  It is NOT a "usability" question but a security question.

Comment: The real trick is properly detecting when all browser windows in the session have closed. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/04/05/understanding-browser-session-lifetime.aspx

Comment: i think its a bad security policy to rely on the browser to expire the session as browsers exiting are not always detectable;  both browsers and computers can crash, power and/or internet access can be lost, etc.

Comment: and without javascript it would be impossible, right? so in reality you are left at the mercy of the timeout. but as this is a "what should be" question rather than "what is", I say they "should" close with the browser.

Comment: jun: with HTTP being stateless, yes, you have to rely on the sesssion timeout - there is no other reliable way of detecting an expired session. While can listen to such events, the best and easiest way is the timeout.

Comment: I guess the "usability" aspect of the question is what is the user expecting will happen.  Do users expect the webpage to log them out if they close it? (closing browser == logging out)  My thought is yes that's an expectation.